# ¿Cómo pongo los años bisiestos entre dos fechas python en número en vez de en lista?

Tags: python

```
date1 = int ( input( "Tell me one date: "))
date2 = int(input("Tell me another date: "))
if date1 < date2:
  print ("Lap years between", date1, "and", date2, "are: ")
while date1 <= date2:
  if date1 % 4 ==0 and date1 % 100 !=0:
    print (date1)
  if date1 % 100==0 and date1 % 400 ==0: 
    print (date1)
  date1 += 1
```

Tengo ya todo esto pero no quiero que me diga todos los años bisiestos en forma de lista sino que me diga cuántos hay en número.

Comment: Puedes usar un contador que inicie en 0 y sumarle 1 cada vez que un año sea bisiesto. Luego abajo del while hacer print(contador)

Comment: Es decir crear una variable antes del while que sea contador=0

Comment: No se muy bien como funciona python y no lo he entendido bien, perdona... He tratado de hacerlo pero me sale mal por lo que algo estaré haciendo mal, ¿qué y dónde exactamente debería poner? Muchas gracias por la rapidez por cierto. @DanteS.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes o bien crear una lista y contar sus elementos (esto si vas a necesitar también almacenar los años), o bien poner un contador como te indica @DanteS.

Contador:

```
date1 = int(input("Tell me one date: "))
date2 = int(input("Tell me another date: "))

counter = 0  # Inicias el contador a 0
if date1 < date2:
    print ("Leap years between", date1, "and", date2, "are: ")
while date1 <= date2:
    if date1 % 4 ==0 and date1 % 100 !=0:
        counter += 1  # En vez de imprimir añades 1 al contador
    if date1 % 100==0 and date1 % 400 ==0: 
      counter += 1  # En vez de imprimir añades 1 al contador
    date1 += 1

print(counter)
```

Almacenando los años en una lista:

```
date1 = int ( input( "Tell me one date: "))
date2 = int(input("Tell me another date: "))
leap_years = []  # Creas una lista vacía
if date1 < date2:
    print ("Leap years between", date1, "and", date2, "are: ")
while date1 <= date2:
    if date1 % 4 ==0 and date1 % 100 !=0:
        leap_years.append(date1)  # Añades el año a la lista
    if date1 % 100==0 and date1 % 400 ==0: 
        leap_years.append(date1)  # Añades el año a la lista
    date1 += 1

print(leap_years, len(leap_years))
```

Esto además de devolverte la lista de años `leap_years`, te devuelve cuantos años hay en esa lista `len(leap_years)`.

**Aclaración sobre tu código**

Puedes también eliminar la parte que verifica `date1 % 100==0` ya que obligas a que cumpla `date1 % 400==0` y si cumple esta última, cumplirá forzosamente la primera.
Por lo tanto podrías dejar esa línea así `if date1 % 400 ==0:`

Y si quieres reducirlo aún más para no repetir el incremento al contador (solo pongo la parte del `while`):

```
while date1 <= date2:
    if date1 % 4 == 0 and date1 % 100 != 0 or date1 % 400 == 0:
        counter += 1
    date1 += 1
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha ayudado un montón y he aprendido como hacerlo :)